# SQL: Update table column passed as variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Any idea how to create this function in t-sql?

Pseudo-code:

```
function( @table, @table_column )
{
    update @table
    set @table_column = replace(@table_column,',','')
    where @table_column like '%,%'
}
```

Ideas I've tried:

1. Procedures: only take readonly tables (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx)
2. Functions: cannot do updates...

Any suggestions?  Thanks everyone!

Update:  I had a database with about 40 tables, each with columns that I needed to remove special characters (i.e., ",").  Although it would be nice to create a function/procedure where I could give it the name and fix the column, I decided instead (based on the comments) to just write each update out.  Perhaps I was just looking for too fancy of a solution to a relatively simple problem.

Comment: Look into stored procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this is [dynamic SQL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).  Unless you are writing database tools, you rarely need to do this kind of thing.  Are you sure your database is designed correctly?  What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a function?

Usually functions are applied to a column inside the select list, such as SELECT MYFUNC(COL1) FROM TAB1;

This can definitely be done in a Stored Procedure with dynamic SQL.  You can even look at a return value for the number of rows updated.

I guess the main question is what is your business requirements??